# Company website does not work in linux, works in Windows

Tags: networking, windows, xubuntu, firefox, chromium

I have recently installed Xubuntu 15.04 in my personal laptop & tried to access my company site thru firefox. I was able to login using otp, but encountered several problems afterwards

1. When i try access the internal sites, I am asked for my network credentials which when entered manually or by keepass2, it returns the login prompt again (I checked the credentials & it's correct). This happened in Firefox
2. When i tried again using chrome, i was able to connect using the network credentials as well, but was unable to open dialog links or pop-ups.

In my windows 7 desktop, using either browser posed no issues at all in accessing the site. What is the possible issue 7 how can i fix this ? I am planning to sell my desktop & switch fully to linux.

Comment: For an internal company website, the IT department (designers and developers) will be the only ones to be able to see why it does not work on your Xubuntu laptop. A speculation would be that something like silverlight (which works in Windows only) is used on the site, along with other possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to comment, but my reputation does not allow this.

You mentioned OTP and this rings a bell.
Several SSL VPNs (which are talking of) store internal credentials and often to this by encrypting these credentials somehow. 
(e.g. with the users password) 
which is difficult with OTP ;-)

So it depends how the internal authentication is performed (which could be different on Windows browsers and Linux).

This is rather vague, but it might be an angle to look at.

But as Soll Illadan pointed out, this is something you need to put to your IT department.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, was in long-ass project. It seems my company has decided during my onsite hiatus to remove everything oss & linux & stick to windows-only enterprise system; leading to no support to linux in any aspect.